# maven-enforcer-plugin and child pom

Tags: maven, parent-pom, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am trying to use the maven-enforcer-plugin to ensure that one profile is activated (requireActiveProfile rule). See the second example on this page: [Require Active Profile](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireActiveProfile.html)

It works well with a single pom file. When I try to use it with 2 pom files (a parent and a child) this do not work anymore when I try to build the child module.

I have any idea why it doesn’t work?

---

### Complete example:

```
EXAMPLE
|   pom.xml <1> (parent pom)
|
\---child
        pom.xml <2> (child pom)
```

#### Parent pom file `<1>`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app.parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>first</id>
      <properties>
        <my-name>Alice</my-name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>second</id>
      <properties>
        <my-name>Bob</my-name>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-first-or-second-profile-is-active</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireActiveProfile>
                  <profiles>first,second</profiles>
                  <all>false</all>
                </requireActiveProfile>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <echo>Hello ${my-name}!</echo>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

#### Child pom file `<2>`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>
```

Now I run:

```
EXAMPLE>cd child
EXAMPLE\child>mvn compile -Psecond
```

And the output looks like that:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-first-or-second-profile-is-active) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireActiveProfile failed with message:
Profile "first" is not activated.
Profile "second" is not activated.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.178 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-30T18:03:50+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/989M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-first-or-second-profile-is-active) on project my-app: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When I run maven on the parent pom, it works. What did I miss?

Comment: Wiithin a multi module you should call the child by changing into it's directory...just call it from root via `mvn -pl child compile -Psecond`

Comment: The problem isn't the multi-module setup, my problem is about `maven-enforcer-plugin` using the `requireActiveProfile` rule and child POM.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maven Profiles are a bit confusing, but I'll venture an explanation based on my experiences.

The profile *definitions* is not inherited, but the *effects* of them are.

If you jump to the `child` directory and run `mvn -Pfirst help:active-profiles` you'll see that the *effect* of the parent's profile is indeed there:

Part of the output:

```
...
<properties>
  <my-name>Alice</my-name>
</properties>
...
```

but you won't see the profiles *definition* in there.

The bad news is that your `enforcer` rule won't work in this scenario, unless every child also defines the required profiles.

The good news is that, armed with this new knowledge, you can use *another* `enforcer` rule (`requireProperty`) to achieve what you want:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-property</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireProperty>
              <property>my-name</property>
              <message>You must set a my-name property! Did you activate the right profile?</message>
            </requireProperty>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Using `requireProperty` is exactly already my workaround for this problem. Thank you for confirming it and explaining why `requireActiveProfile` is not usable in my case.

Comment: Thanks for this... this workaround is the best option I found... I've declared my "dev-env" profile with "<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>" and the other profiles ("dev-test" and "dev-prod") with a property called "<deployable>true</deployable>"... now I can execute my build with "mvn clean install -P dev-test" and it will work correctly... it's important to note that now I can't execute "mvn clean install" for the default "env-dev" profile... but that's no problem as I do not need it to run my project locally... in that case, I can just comment the plugin... thanks!